# Relationship between Omega and X and notation

Tags: random-variable, notation

I have read that random variables X are a functions $ X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbf{R} $. $ X(\omega) = ...$ E.g. $ X(\omega) = mean(\omega)$ (is this correct?)
So then $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ are realisations of $X$. But how do I just get $\omega$ or notate it if I don't want to transform it? I have never seen any greek letters for variables but population parameters. So when I don't want e.g. the mean and just $\omega$ is $X(\omega) = \omega$?

Comment: $X(\omega)$ is a function from $\Omega$ to a measurable space $E$, often with $E=\mathbb R$ but it does not have to be.  There is no need for $\Omega$ to be $\mathbb R$ and it typically will not be, especially if you have multiple random variables which are not functions of each other

Comment: If $\Omega=\{\omega_1,\omega_2\}$ where $\omega_1$ is "heads" and $\omega_2$ is "tails", you cannot say $X(\omega)=\omega$. $X$ should be a number, not "heads" or "tails". In the same vein, you cannot take the mean of "heads" and "tails". You would also have trouble defining mean without having defined a corresponding probability space and a corresponding random variable.